# Add CSS class to unpublished node items

Tags: views, theming, nodes, hooks

I am showing nodes from a 'news' content type in a view. In this view I want to add a CSS class to the unpublished items. So, am I able to style (e.g. red background color) on the unpublished items?

How can I do this? Is there a way to write a hook in `template.php`?

Comment: Don't nodes by default already have a class like `node-unpublished`?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. In your theme's template.php:

```
function mytemplate_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node && isset($node->nid)) {
    if ($node->status) {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'published';
    } else {
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'unpublished';
    }
  }
}
```

You need to define classes_array with whatever classes you need to be added.